# OVH VPS, xampp, mysql and remote mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, vps, ovh

I'm working on an OVH VPS that's primarily a game server.  It runs a MariaDB/MySQL database setup via xampp, and I would like to connect to said mysql/game server via PHP from another server that hosts the website located elsewhere (not localhost/127.0.0.1).

I tried turning off the firewalls to see if it would allow me to connect but I still cannot.
I have created a users using HeidieSQL to allow remote connects (%) with a username and password.

All I seem to get is the error on my PHP side `Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused`.  I also had a similar message displayed when I tried to use curl to retrieve a json file from a specific port (it was viewable via browser but refused connection when connecting with PHP Curl).

What do you recommend to try to be able to connect to the server?